# WKWebView crashes when intensely using the camera

Tags: ios, camera, crash, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

Given a Web-based App running in a `WKWebView` instance **taking photos** using the camera.

- 1st version using `<input type="file" capture="camera"/>` **inside** the Web view.
- 2nd version using `UIImagePickerController`, then transfer the image to the Web view.

After taking about 50 photos, **both versions** cause the `WkWebView` to be replaced by a white rectangle.

First guess was memory leaking in the JavaScript, but tests resulted in crashes even when **not** processing the image data **at all**, also when the Web view is virtually empty and **even** when the `UIImagePickerController` is not connected to the Web view **at all**.

Profiling of the iOS app shows no notable increases in memory usage, but *other processes* (as listed in the XCode debugger) show short peaks of about 100 MB in memory usage immediately after taking a photo.

I understand the `WKWebView` is run in a separate process which can get killed by iOS when resources are short, **but** this happens also on more recent hardware.

How does iOS decide to kill the Web view and how to prevent it when just taking photos?

Comment: Facing absolutely same behaviour with WKWebView with html file saved on disk (~25k pixels content height) and a few images, also saved on disk. Another case - I have <div contenteditable=true></div>. And putting caret inside editable area cause a white view or crash from time to time.

Comment: @Daniel have you found anything on this?

Comment: @Daniel, I know this post is old, but did you ever have any luck with this issue?

Comment: I no longer work on this app. My best guess would be to work around the problem by detecting the crash and then forcing the web view to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Wkwebview crash fixed on open camera upload file

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allows you to take a photo or video.</string>
```